# How to draw card from deck without repeating in C?

Tags: c, arrays, playing-cards

I shuffled the array but now I need a function to draw a card from the array in the order of the shuffled deck. I can't seem to figure out how to draw the next card in the deck. How would I increment to the next card everytime I draw a card? Would I use some sort of counter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 52 

void initDeck();
void shuffle();
int draw(int d[]);

int deck[SIZE];
int sdeck[SIZE];

int main()
{
    initDeck();
    shuffle();

    return 0;
}

void initDeck(){
    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < SIZE; i++){
        deck[i] = i + 1;
    }
}

void shuffle(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < SIZE; i++){
        sdeck[i] = deck[i];
    }

    i = 0;

    for(i = SIZE; i > 0; i--){
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        int temp = sdeck[i];
        sdeck[i] = sdeck[j];
        sdeck[j] = temp;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d,", sdeck[i]);
    }

}

/**int draw(int d[]){
    int k=0;
    k = d[k];
    return(k);
}**/
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com, but could probably use some more cleanup before posting there.

Comment: You might want to search the "Kunth Shuffle".  The general way to do this is to "draw" a random card by picking a random card and then swapping it with the last card -- then reducing the size of the deck by one.  Which means SIZE would no longer be a constant.

Comment: If you have shuffled the deck, draw the first card, then the second and so on. Yes, you "use some sort of counter".

Comment: @MooseBoys No it would definitely not be appropriate for codereview since since that site is for working code.

Comment: the question title is wrong. The problem is simply that you're *not* drawing the card from the deck, instead you just always peek at the first card.

Comment: But your shuffle code has a `for` loop at the bottom which does exactly what you're asking for: it dumps the shuffled cards one by one. You didn't write this code at all; it's the given part of your homework.

Comment: `int i = 0; for (i; i < SIZE; i++)` should either be `int i; for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++)` or `for (int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)`. The code you have generates a warning: *"expression result unused [-Wunused-value]"*

Comment: In the `shuffle` function, you start with `i = SIZE`, and then access `sdeck[i]`. That's reading beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior. Even worse, `j` could be equal to `SIZE` on the first iteration of the loop, which will write a value beyond the end of the array.

Comment: First, move srand() into main, where it belongs. Then, your "draw" function, whatever it is, has to keep track of how many cards have been drawn from the deck, otherwise, you just keep dealing the top card over and over.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sdeck[SIZE];
int num_dealt = 0;
. . .
void shuffle() {
    . . .
    num_dealt = 0;
}

int draw() {
    int c = sdeck[num_dealt];
    num_dealt += 1;
    return c;
}
```

Next step is to make deck a structure that includes both the cards and the count, and pass the structure to draw() rather than using globals.